# c# .net Postback usercontrol when user clicks on page button

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a 'master' page "Page" with tabs 1, 2, 3.  I have a usercontrol (child) with a form in it.  When someone clicks on a different tab (in Page), i need the usercontrol to postback so i can save the form values.

The problem is controls in 'master' Page are in the wrong viewstate to postback the usercontrol form.  If i call the usercontrol from the Page only auto-posted back data is available.  Obviously i dont want to autopostback every field.  Just would be nice to postback the usercontrol on event from Page.

I've tried calling a save button from Page but obviously it has no client data in it--it postsback empty.

'master' Page: Portal.aspx

```
<%@ Page Trace="true"  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Portal.aspx.cs" Inherits="MT2Web.Portal" EnableViewState="true" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server" style="padding: 0px">

           <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
                    <!-- Nav tabs -->

                    <asp:BulletedList CssClass="nav nav-tabs" ID="userNav"      onclick="userNav_Click" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton"   EnableViewState="False" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <asp:ListItem class="active" Value="0">Login:               </asp:ListItem>

                        <asp:ListItem Value="New">New +</asp:ListItem>

                    </asp:BulletedList>

                </div>
            </div>

 </form>
```

---

Page Controller: Portal.aspx.cs

```
//loads the usercontroller:
Controls.Workflow.Racking Workflow_Racking= (Controls.Workflow.Racking)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Workflow/Racking.ascx");

    container.Controls.Add(Workflow_Racking); // note:  dynamically loaded usercontrols usually cant be called by id (Workflow_Racking)

//call a method to the usercontrol to postback



    public void userNav_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
    {
Controls.Workflow.Racking ucRacking = (Controls.Workflow.Racking)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Workflow/Racking.ascx");

ucRacking.PartialSave();  //method on UserControl page that i called (didnt work)}
```

---

```
UserControl:  Racking.ascx.cs

    public void PartialSave()
    {
        Validator = new MT2Logic.Validation.RackingValidator();

        Validator.Context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Please write some codes. It is not enough to find the situation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask